# What are authentic research sources and where can I find them?

Tags: research, health-education

This is an issue I face not only doing legal research, but also on medical searches.

In my case, I was searching for a highly detailed picture of the human circulatory system, but simply searching on duckduckgo, yandex or google for images brings up dozens of different images, from the weirdest webpages, each showing the circulatory system with more or less details. The image from Wikipedia is still one of the better ones, but the blood vessels are too over-simplified.
For sure medical researchers once must have made such detailed images of it from where all these derive, but where can I find the true sources?

Similar when searching for a question. Most results are abstruse websites with faint or no citation to actual research papers or studies.

**Q:** Is there a archive or a web portal from where I can get such information and educational stuff?
Wikipedia seems like still the best option, but also Wikipedia doesn't has everything and can be fairly limited on some topics.

Comment: for purely research articles: pubmed, google scholar and ncbi

Answer (score 3):

Medical students and researchers in the medical/biological/health sciences typically use textbooks with their coursework. Focusing on your example of the circulatory system, you will find both general information in a general anatomy or physiology textbook and more specific information in a textbook focused on cardiovascular anatomy. A general physiology or anatomy textbook almost certainly contains aspects of the most obvious anatomy: the heart itself, great vessels, pulmonary circulation, and possibly a bit of the peripheral anatomy with high clinical relevance like carotid/renal/femoral arteries.

For anatomical reference, [Gray's Anatomy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gray%27s_Anatomy) remains a beautiful and comprehensive reference. Public domain images from Gray's are commonly found on Wikipedia; you can also often find lecture notes from academic courses in searches on standard search engines you mention - these are likely to be more reliable than other websites you find.

The usefulness of more specifics on circulatory system anatomy in particular are limited by the extent of variation from person to person; a more detailed diagram may not actually be more useful if it doesn't represent the actual subjects you see.

Comment: As a side note, get hold of the full version, not the one "for students" if you can. @KrischnaGabriel

Comment: One example of anatomical variation came up in a Biology.SE question here: https://biology.stackexchange.com/questions/82918/coronary-circulation This is a variation in the circulation feeding the *heart itself* where only ~70% of the population has the "standard" anatomy.